# Taking item from string array that *might* be there

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a string array, and it may contain an element with the text "mytext" within the string. eg:

```
mystringarray
{
    [0] => "hello world";
    [1] => "some of mytext";
}
```

I also have an array that doesn't have the mytext text in it.

```
mystringarray
{
    [0] => "hello world";
    [1] => "some of notmy";
}
```

My problem is when I use:

```
string mytextdata = mystringarray.Single<string>(t => t.Contains("mytext")).ToString();
```

I get an exception for the second array as it can't find an element that matches the expression.

Is there a quick way I can edit this one line to not throw an exception if it finds nothing, and instead just ignore? I have a lot of these lines and I don't want to have to wrap each in an if statement.

Apologies if question isn't clear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
string mytextdata = mystringarray.SingleOrDefault<string>(t => t.Contains("mytext"));
```

This will return `null` if nothing is found, otherwise it will return a `string`, so you don't need the `ToString()`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Maybe  you can use the [`FirstOrDefault()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx) method. Well - I just realized that there is a [`SingleOrDefault()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451.aspx), too.

Comment: since AndyC is expecting only single element thus solution proposed by Dnaiel is right for him.

Comment: @Usman: I realized that there is a SingleOrDefault ... as I wrote - no reason to downvote